# Django duplicate queries with manager related

Tags: django, django-admin, django-queryset, prefetch

I'm working on optimizing my ORM queries. I have two apps, 'app1' and 'app2'. One class of 'app2' has a foreign key to a class of app1 as follows:

```
#app1/models.py
class C1App1(WithDateAndOwner):
  def get_c2_app2(self):
    res = self.c2app2_set.all()
    if res.count() > 0:
      return res[0]
    else:
      return None

#app2/models.py
class C2App2(WithDateAndOwner):
  c1app1 = models.ForeignKey("app1.C1App1")
  is_ok = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now I display the C2App2 for all instances of C1App1 in the admin page:

```
#app1/admin.py
@admin.register(C1App1)
class C1App1Admin(admin.MyAdmin):
  list_display = ("get_c2_app2")
  list_select_related = ()
  list_prefetch_related = ("c2app2_set",)
  list_per_page = 10
```

`prefetch_related` reduces this query:

```
SELECT ••• FROM `app2_c2app2` WHERE `app2_c2app2`.`c1app1_id` = 711
  Duplicated 19 times.
```

to:

```
SELECT ••• FROM `app2_c2app2` WHERE `app2_c2app2`.`c1app1_id` IN (704, 705, 706, 707, 708, 709, 710, 711, 702, 703) ORDER BY `app2_c2app2`.`id` DESC
```

And it's fine. Now if I want to filter the query on C2App2's attribute 'is_ok':

```
#app1/models.py
class C1App1(WithDateAndOwner):
  def get_c2_app2(self):
    res = self.c2app2_set.filter(is_ok=False)
    if res.count() > 0:
      return res[0]
    else:
      return None
```

I still have this prefetched query:

```
SELECT ••• FROM `c2app2_set` WHERE `app2_c2app2`.`c1app1_id` IN (704, 705, 706, 707, 708, 709, 710, 711, 702, 703) ORDER BY `app2_c2app2`.`id` DESC
```

but with that one duplicated for each displayed instance of C1App1 (10).  :

```
SELECT ••• FROM `app2_c2app2` WHERE (`app2_c2app2`.`c1app1_id` = 711 AND `app2_c2app2`.`is_ok` = 1)
  Duplicated 13 times.
```

Actually the query is also duplicated again for 3 ids out of the 10 displayed, which results in those 13 duplicated queries. What can I do in order to not duplicate those queries? It seems the prefetch_related doesn't help anymore here.

Comment: did u try `.select_related()` instead of `.prefetch_related()`?

Comment: Putting `c2app2_set` in the `list_select_related`? yes I did it by mistake and it doesn't work since `c2app2` is not a foreign key of `c1app1`. It's the opposite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

prefetch_related only works when you use `.all()`.
If you apply any other transformations like `.filter()`, the new DB query will be made. This is because `prefetch_related` simply caches ALL related instances in list, so Django cannot perform `filter()` on list. To solve your issue you should use [Prefetch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) object.
You can pass `queryset` parametr to it. So, instead of using list_prefetch_related, override `get_queryset` method in your admin class.

```
def get_queryset(*args, **kwargs):
     qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
     qs = qs.prefetch_related(Prefetch('c2app2_set', queryset=C2App2.objects.filter(is_ok=False)))
     return qs
```

And

```
class C1App1(WithDateAndOwner):
   def get_c2_app2(self):
      res = self.c2app2_set.all()
      if res.count() > 0:
         return res[0]
      else:
         return None
```